# Switch new hard drive with old hard drive (containing files)

Tags: hard-drive, operating-systems, desktop-computer

So my old pc is dead. I took off the HDD cause my files are in there. 
I have this new pc but the hdd is only 80gb. There are no important files in there so i can just throw it away. I want to switch it with my old HDD. But:

1. I cant just plug in the old hdd to my new pc right?
2. If not, how can i switch to that old hdd without losing my files?
3. Will there be risk for my new pc when I plug in that old HDD (i mean i dont want to have 2 dead PCs)

(My first plan was actually just adding the old HDD but my pc doesnt have room left for that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching your OS HDD between different machines typically won't work unless the hardware is identical between the systems. You'll end up with a lot of troubleshooting if it does by some chance boot.

An easier option with less headaches would simply be to buy an external [HDD enclosure](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/external-hard-drive-enclosure), install your old HDD in that, and then simply plug it into your new machine via USB and transfer any of the files you want to your new machine's HDD.

Comment: Is an external HDD enclosure different than a external portable drive? That is actually possible. I can just permanently plug it in and I'd have an instant external drive. But will windows treat that as simply a removable disk?

Comment: I checked my local store and looked for hdd enclosures.. I find it confusing that some are 2x the price and some are cheap. I dont get it. I mean, its just an enclosure. Basically a case for my drive. Am i right?

Comment: Yep, all a portable HDD is, is a drive inside an enclosure like that. The price difference usually comes down to aesthetics, or if they offer certain ports, like firewire. You should be fine with the fairly cheap ones - and yes, you can leave them plugged in as long as you like and Windows will treat them as any other external drive.

Comment: Thats cool. Ive read some faqs about them and.. its possible to have errors? I mean im kinda bothered. what if i cant see the files i stored in my old hdd.

Comment: I've never had a problem with them. So long as you're careful with the HDD, and it wasn't damaged when your old PC decided to die, you should be absolutely fine.

Comment: How do you even take care of your HDD? I mean its just sitting here in front of me.

Comment: As long as you haven't dropped it, or damaged the PCB or ports, it should be fine - that's about all you need to worry about physically. I've damaged a HDD PCB once when removing it from an old machine as it was a quite hard to unplug, and I was a little rough with the connectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you old HD has Windows 7/8 installed, install it into your new PC and see if it boots. The hardware does **not** have to be identical.

Best case scenario: Windows will install the proper drivers for new hardware upon first/second boot and run perfectly.

Worst case scenario: Windows won't boot.. in which case you can install the old HD as a 2nd internal drive or purchase a [reliable external enclosure](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007705&IsNodeId=1&Description=hard%20drive%20enclosure&bop=And&Order=RATING&PageSize=20) of corresponding size and interface to access your files.

Comment: My old HDD is using XP. My new pc is using XP. Ive read somewhere that its probably not a good idea. Especially now that my 2 hardware arent even identical. I wont take the risk so im going with the HDD enclosure.. IF i find something that is cheap here.